# SQLite3::SQLException: no such column

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sqlite

I'm trying to build an app where people can specify what posts need to be read before this one and here I'm trying to show them.

```
  <%= @post.before.each do |before| %>
  <li><%= before.title %></li>
  <% end %>
```

This gets me this error:

```
SQLite3::SQLException: no such column: connections.post_id: SELECT "posts".* FROM "posts" INNER JOIN "connections" ON "posts"."id" = "connections"."after_id" WHERE "connections"."post_id" = ?
```

There isn't supposed to be a post_id column in connections, there is supposed to be an before_id column in it.

My models are:

post.rb:

```
class Post < ApplicationRecord
    has_many :connections
    has_many :before, through: :connections, source: :after, foreign_key: "before_id"
    has_many :after, through: :connections, source: :before, foreign_key: "after_id"
end
```

connection.rb

```
class Connection < ApplicationRecord
    belongs_to :before, class_name: "Post", foreign_key: "before_id"
    belongs_to :after, class_name: "Post", foreign_key: "after_id"
end
```

The controller code for posts - automatically generated with scaffolding:

```
class PostsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_post, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  # GET /posts
  # GET /posts.json
  def index
    @posts = Post.all
  end

  # GET /posts/1
  # GET /posts/1.json
  def show
  end

  # GET /posts/new
  def new
    @post = Post.new
  end

  # GET /posts/1/edit
  def edit
  end

  # POST /posts
  # POST /posts.json
  def create
    @post = Post.new(post_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @post.save
        format.html { redirect_to @post, notice: 'Post was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @post }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @post.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # PATCH/PUT /posts/1
  # PATCH/PUT /posts/1.json
  def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @post.update(post_params)
        format.html { redirect_to @post, notice: 'Post was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @post }
      else
        format.html { render :edit }
        format.json { render json: @post.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # DELETE /posts/1
  # DELETE /posts/1.json
  def destroy
    @post.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to posts_url, notice: 'Post was successfully destroyed.' }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end

  private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_post
      @post = Post.find(params[:id])
    end

    # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
    def post_params
      params.require(:post).permit(:title, :text)
    end
end
```

Comment: (1) You should add the whole error to your question (copy and paste from your console and add it to your question - don't put it in the comments), as it's easier to help you that way, (2) I'm pretty sure that snippet you provided is not where your problem lies, so you should probably show us your controller code, too, (3) you don't want to do `<%= @post.before.each do |before| %>` rather you want to do `<%- @post.before.each do |before| %>`, (4) `before` and `after` are sort of terrible model names IMO (no offense meant, just an observation).

Comment: (1) Didn't I? (2) That was automatically generated so I doubt it will be useful, but I still added it now. (3) That didn't make a difference. (4) Maybe I'll switch to post and dependencies.

Answer (score 1):

`has_many :connections` in your `Post` model is telling Rails that you have a `post_id` on the `connections` table.  If this is not the case, I recommend deleting the association or defining a `foreign_key` for the association.

I would recode your model as follows:

```
class Post < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :before, class_name: 'Connection', foreign_key: "before_id"
  has_many :after, class_name: 'Connection',  foreign_key: "after_id"
end
```

NOTE: You have `source: :before` and `source: :after` set opposite their respective association names and foreign_key names.  I suspect that was not intentional.  However, if it was intentional, you may want to swap foreign_keys between your two associations (i.e put the `before_id` on the `after` association and vis versa).

Comment: Now I don't get an error anymore, but it also doesn't show anything, and the edit view doesn't let me specify related posts anymore.

Comment: Check your `source` like I mentioned in the note above. Also, were you using the `connections` association elsewhere?  Post your edit view if you would like me to take a look at it.